# Initial Traces created by Spring-Cloud-Gateway are all named "/", no matter the path

Tags: stackdriver, spring-cloud-sleuth, spring-cloud-gateway, google-cloud-trace

I've integrated sleuth into my application gateway and the services behind it. The traces in Stackdriver (GKE) look good but the root-span is always named "/". For example:

[image: for example]

The second span is also created by the gateway and has a much better name.

How can i configure sleuth in my gateway-service to use a different naming or fix whatever causes two spans?

**EDIT1**:

I created a minimal project with spring-gateway, sleuth and gcp and wrote a LoggingReporter to print all reported spans while having GCP auto-config working.

`StackdriverHttpClientParser` names spans based by the request uri. The second span is created by the TraceWebFilter based on a request with the full uri. the first span is created by the `HttpClientBeanPostProcessor` based on the uri "/".

I don't think this is a gcp issue. it is probably a problem with spring-gateway. Interestingly the TraceWebFilter span is created first, but the PostProcessor one is still the parent.

**EDIT2**: I created an issue in spring sleuth https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-sleuth/issues/1535

Comment: That might be a problem with stackdriver. You'd have to see if you have the same issue when running it offline

Answer (score 1):

I'm agreed with comment made by Marcin, the problem could be on Stackdriver and you can validate this by running a trace in your environment (offline) and  also by be assured that the `x-cloud-trace-context: TRACE_ID/SPAN_ID` is formatted correctly, as per what I have seen there are three ways to do it and are mentioned [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-gcp/docs/1.0.0.RELEASE/reference/html/_spring_cloud_sleuth.html).

If the trace results successful by running it offline without changing anything then the problem is with stackdriver.

Comment: i debuged into a sample project and added my findings. this does not seem to be a GCP specific problem.